# Shiny server (Ubuntu) exporting multiple pdf not working

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I have a problem in my shiny app when deployed in a shiny server.
To be clear, the problem only occurs when running from the server. When the app is run in my local computer it works perfectly.

I have a long code for my app but the problem is in a downloadHandler expression. I have a button to export multiple plots in a single pdf file. However, when clicking the button nothing happens.
My server code is:

```
  output$kinetic<-downloadHandler(
    filename="All plots.pdf",
    content=function(file){
      withProgress(message = 'Exporting', min=0,max=1, { 
        pdf(file, width=14, height=8)
        for (i in 0:((length(fitting()$kinetics)/2)-1)){
          
print(cowplot::plot_grid(fitting()$kinetics[[(2*i)+1]],fitting()$raw[[(2*i)+1]],fitting()$kinetics[[(2*i)+2]],fitting()$raw[[(2*i)+2]],ncol=2,nrow=2))
          incProgress(i/((length(fitting()$kinetics)/2)-1))
        }
        dev.off()
      })
    }
  )
```

As I mentioned, the code work on my local computer. but not when deployed in the server.
I tested removing the for loop in the server and it works fine. I've also tested other R packages to export the graph like ggpubr:ggarrange() or grid::pushViewport() but so far neither works.

Any ideas of what could be happening?

I've check all the logs in the server but there is no error message.

UPDATE:
I think I found the issue. Is taking more than 60s to create and download the pdf document.
By default, the shiny server have a 60s timeout and that is why is not working. I've been trying to bypass that setting but so far I haven't been successful.

If you have more ideas let me know.